# Drupal: permissions on nodes

Tags: drupal-6

I want to set permissions to nodes based on user roles. Note: I need to set permissions on nodes, not content type.

What is the way out for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module http://drupal.org/project/content_access (Content Access) allows you to set custom permissions on each individual node by user roles.

Once installed, there will be a tab called 'Access Control' on your nodes where you will be able to set these permissions.